# Fetching parent attribute xml only when a child node is present using xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

I have below xml :

```
<root>
    <steps>
        <step Name="test1" >
        <stepDetails Name = "exception" />
        <steps Name="1" />
        </step>
        <step Name="test2" >
        <steps Name="2" />
        </step>
        <step Name="test3" >
        <steps Name="3" />
        </step>
        <step Name="test4" >
        <stepDetails Name = "valid" />
        <steps Name="1" />
        </step>
    </steps>
<root>
```

I wan to get the name of all Steps except those having StepDetails name as 'exception'. Please note that StepDetails is not present in all Step.

In this example, I should receive the output as test2, test3 and test3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`xpath`** expression:

```
//step[./stepDetails/@Name != 'exception' or not(./stepDetails)]/@Name
```